# Calculate the Gödel number of the band function

Tags: logic, prime-numbers, computer-science, turing-machines

I am looking at the following:

Compute the Gödel number of the tape function that describes the band on which the word COMPREHENSIBILITY stands, where the symbol $H$ is written on
Tape at position $0$. The rest of the tape is empty. The indexing of
the characters should be in alphabetical order, i.e. $C  \rightarrow 1$, $E  \rightarrow 2$, etc.

$$$$

Could you explain to me what "*the symbol $H$ is written on
Tape at position $0$*" means?

How can we use this information?

The word COMPREHENSIBILITY has $17$ letters. So do we consider the first $17$ prime numbers and take as exponents the indices of each letter to calculate the Gödel number?

Comment: I think we need some more background to be able to interpret this question  ... the reference to 'band' and the $H$ on the 'Tape' at position $0$ is indeed rather cryptic ... Also: there are many different possible Godel numberings.  Are you looking at a book?

Comment: I am looking some notes, but they are in german... Do you speak german? @Bram28

Comment: A little .. probably not enough

Comment: As for "band" I meant "tape". As for "the symbol H is written on Tape at position 0" I haven't found anything related in my notes. Do we maybe consider just the letters after "H" ? The Gödel number is defined as follows: https://ibb.co/y6CtV4R @Bram28

Comment: OK, I can actually follow the German just fine ... I see that there is a mapping from the natural numbers to the symbols used by the machine... which I assume is the function that indicates what is on the tape ... but this would assume that the tape is only a one-sided infinite tape rather than a 2-sided infinite tape ... can you confirm that?  If so, then I am still confused about this $H$ ... I thought maybe with the $H$ at position $0$, the $B$ would end up at position $5$, and the $P$ at $-3$ ... but that would suggest a 2-sided tape ... and it also would not work with the encoding.

Comment: So yes, you might be right: maybe only consider the part of the word that starts with $H$.

Answer (score 1):

It probably means that you only encode the part of the word starting with the $H$ ... the letters before the $H$ are in the 'negative' part of the tape and don't get encoded (which is weird ... but hey)

Also, the $B$ comes before the $C$, so the indexing should be::

$B \to 1$

$C \to 2$

$E \to 3$

$H \to 4$

$I \to 5$

$L \to 6$

$M \to 7$

$N \to 8$

$O \to 9$

$P \to 10$

$R \to 11$

$S \to 12$

$T \to 13$

$Y \to 14$

So, the coding is:

$$2^4 \cdot 3^3 \cdot 5^8 \cdot 7^{11} \cdot 11^5 \cdot 13^1 \cdot 17^5 \cdot 19^6 \cdot 23^5 \cdot 29^{13} \cdot 31^{14}$$

Comment: @MaryStar Given that the letters appear on the tape, even if it is in the 'negative' part of the tape, means that they are part of the alphabet, and hence should be included in the indexing. Indeed, note that I did indeed letters like the $C$, $M$, and $R$ in the indexing, even though they only occur before the $H$, not after.

Comment: Ahh ok!! I have a question.. When at "COMPREHENSIBILITY" we consider at the calculation only the part "HENSIBILITY" would the Gödel number be the same for each word, that has "HENSIBILITY" in it and "H" would be on position $0$ ?

Comment: The Gödel number should be unique for each word, or not?

Comment: I heard someone discussing about the part that "H" is on position $0$ and he told that we consider all odd numbers to the left and all even numbers to the right from $0$. But I don't know what that could mean. Do you maybe have an idea?

Comment: @MaryStar Yes. You could say that the letter immediately to the left of $H$ is in position $1$, the letter immediately the the right of $H$ in position $2$, the letter two places to the left of $H$ in position $3$, the letter two places to the right of $H$ in position $4$, etc. So that way all letters (and indeed all squares) are in a positive position, and hence you can encode the whole tape, even if it is infinite on both sides.

Comment: Ahh ok!! If we consider that way, then is the calculation that we thought at the beginning wrong?

Comment: @MaryStar Yes, if we use this encoding, then the other calculation is clearly wrong!

Comment: But if we didn't have the hint to consider all odd numbers to the left and all even numbers to the right from 0, then the way you proposed were correct, or not? But when at "COMPREHENSIBILITY" we consider at the calculation only the part "HENSIBILITY" would the Gödel number be the same for each word, that has "HENSIBILITY" in it and "H" would be on position $0$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar Well, it's most likely either one of those two, yes.  The problem statement isn't any clearer?

Comment: No, at the problem we don't get any other information. But would all these words, that have "HENSIBILITY" in it and "H" would be on position $0$, have the same Gödel number? If yes, is this possible or should every tape function have a unique Gödel number?

Comment: @MaryStar It makes more sense that every distinct tape has a distinct encoding, so I do like the second method.

Comment: Ah ok!! So if we do that with the second method, would we get the following?$$G(COMPREHENSIBILITY)=G(HEERNPSMIOBCI\_L\_I\_T\_Y)$$ where $\_$ is an empty position since on the left side we don't have any letters any more.

Comment: $$=p_1^{\text{ind}(H)}\cdot p_2^{\text{ind}(E)}\cdot p_3^{\text{ind}(E)}\cdot p_4^{\text{ind}(R)}\cdot p_5^{\text{ind}(N)}\cdot p_6^{\text{ind}(P)}\cdot p_7^{\text{ind}(S)}\cdot p_8^{\text{ind}(M)}\cdot p_9^{\text{ind}(I)}\cdot p_{10}^{\text{ind}(O)}\cdot p_{11}^{\text{ind}(B)}\cdot p_{12}^{\text{ind}(C)}\cdot p_{13}^{\text{ind}(I)}\cdot p_{14}^{\text{ind}(\_)}\cdot p_{15}^{\text{ind}(L)}\cdot p_{16}^{\text{ind}(\_)}\cdot p_{17}^{\text{ind}(I)}\cdot p_{18}^{\text{ind}(\_)}\cdot p_{19}^{\text{ind}(T)}\cdot p_{20}^{\text{ind}(\_)}\cdot p_{21}^{\text{ind}(Y)}$$

Comment: where $p_i^{\text{ind}(\_)}=1$ and the indices of the letters as in your answer. Is that correct?

Comment: @MaryStar Yes, that wpuld be correct!

Comment: Ok!! Are there also other possibilities to make the calculation, I mean instead of considering one letter at the left of $H$ then one at the right of $H$, etc?

Comment: I have a question... If we rearrange the letters in that way do we not calculate the Gödel number of the tape function that calculates $HEERNPSMIOBCI\_L\_I\_T\_Y$ instead of $COMPREHENSIBILITY$ ? Why can we rearrange the letters and get the Gödel number  for the original word?

Comment: @MaryStar it is because you are not encoding a word, but a tape.